# How to fetch data asynchronously in componentDidMount by Axios

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

I am trying this way:-

```
state = {
    profiles: [],
    data: []
}

async componentDidMount() {
    try {
     // this commented code works. But I want to use axios api.
    //   const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/all/profile`);
    //   const json = await response.json();
    //   this.setState({ data: json });
    //   const json = await response.json();
        let response = await CurdApi.getAllProfiles(); // response always undefined. 

        this.setState({ data: response });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}
```

My CurdApi class is here:-

```
export default class CurdApi {

  static async getAllProfiles() {
    await axios({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/all/profile',
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'json',
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
      return error.data;
    });
  }
}
```

I am new in ReactJs as well as in JS. I don't understand how to use this async/ await correctly. I have to render this data when I fetch this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple use case of async-await in  JS:

```
async function asyncFunc() {
      const data = await axios.get("/url_endpoint")
                         .then((response) => return response.data)

      return data;
}
```

Async function return a promise and Await can only be used inside an async block.
you can call this function in ComponentDidMount() method of class component.
I think you can remove async from componentDidMount and await inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `await` and `then`.

```
export default class CurdApi {

static async getAllProfiles() {

    return await axios({
     url: 'http://localhost:8080/all/profile',
     method: 'GET',
     responseType: 'json',
   })

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getAllProfiles` doesn't have a return statement, so it isn't returning anything. The `.then` callbacks do have return statements, but those just return from their inner functions, not the outer function. I'd recommend embracing async/await and changing it to:

```
static async getAllProfiles() {
  const response = await axios({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/all/profile',
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'json',
  })
  return response.data;
}
```